# How to draw a star using Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Let's say a function named draw_star takes 2 parameters: size and points, as:

```
def draw_star(size,points):
```

And if I were to call the function using

```
draw_star(100, 9)
```

the output should be like this
[image]

The reference I was given is this:

```
import turtle as t
for x in range(18):
    t.forward(100)
    if x%2 == 0:
        t.left(175)
    else:
        t.left(225)
```

now if I call `draw_star(100,7)`, I want it to draw the same star but with 7 points

Comment: And did that reference work? If not, how does the output need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import turtle as t

def draw_star(size, points):
    tipcorner = 5
    cavity = ( 360+points*tipcorner )/points #get corner between tips 
    for x in range(points*2):
        t.forward(size)
        if x % 2 == 0:
            t.left(180-tipcorner)
        else:
            t.right(180-cavity)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your question?

If you want to convert the reference to a function you can do it like this:

```
import turtle as t

def draw_star(size, points):
    for x in range(points):
        t.forward(size)
        if x % 2 == 0:
            t.left(175)
        else:
            t.left(225)
```

Now you can call the function: `draw_star(100, 18)`

The reference you were given works and creates an 18 point star